# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In Jquery replace the space character to '%20'. but working in other forms not in single form. in consists header as

```
<header>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</header>
```

the code using in other form its working well.

```
var vname = $("#EarningsTypes").val();
vname = vname.trim().replace(/ /g, '%20');
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: vname is undefined... there is nothing in it

Comment: Can include `#EarningTypes` element `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined in Jquery

that means, the variable `vname` is `undefined`. To prevent this error from occurring, you can use the ternary operator to set the default value of the string to empty string when it is `undefined`.

```
var vname = $("#EarningsTypes").val() == undefined ? '' : $("#EarningsTypes").val().trim();
vname = vname.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

You can also use `||` to set the default value

```
var vname = $("#EarningsTypes").val() || '';
```

---

If you're using an older browser that doesn't support `trim`, you can use [polyfill from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill)

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g, '');
  };
}
```

Comment: or just use this:  `var vname = $("#EarningsTypes").val() || ""`.

Answer (score 0):

that means the variable vname is undefined. To this error from occurring, you can use optional chaining operator `(?.)` .

The optional chaining operator `(?.)` enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is `nullish` (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`. When used with function calls, it returns `undefined` if the given function does not exist.

This results in shorter and simpler expressions when accessing chained properties when the possibility exists that a reference may be missing. It can also be helpful while exploring the content of an object when there's no known guarantee as to which properties are required.

```
vname = vname?.trim()
```